# How to create an ItemTemplate for a ComboBox programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to create an `ItemTemplate` for a `ComboBox` programmatically (like the topic says).

At the moment I have an `ItemTemplate` in XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBox_EntityCreation_GroupSelect_Style" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}    {1} Mitglied(er)">
                                <Binding Path="Name"/>
                                <Binding Path="MemberCount"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

As a result of my hatred for XAML I would like to get the result without XAML.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If you hate XAML then why use WPF?

Comment: It is possible, all XAML tags are just CLR classes. Just start with `t = new DataTemplate();` It will be a lot more work though.

Comment: What is the reason you dislike XAML so much? Xaml has every feature that languages have.

Comment: Some of my windows are designed with XAML but I try to design smaller dialogs without XAML.
Thanks Henk for you answer, I will look for more about DataTemplate()

Comment: @abhishek I don't like it because I think it is too difficult. I don't want to spend about 2 years to learn XAML in order to design my controls without any bigger problems. For my current project I decided to use it as little as possible.

Comment: @Skadier I think the otherwise. If you learn WPF construct for once, it would be lot easier to code rather than going through writing in C#. There are lot of API that you need to consider in code rather XAML is made simple to write. 
BTW, Check I have converted the code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just converted this on the fly. Please check whether it works.

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(ComboBox));
var d = new DataTemplate();

MultiBinding mb = new MultiBinding();
mb.StringFormat = "{0} {1} Mitglied(er)";
mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Name"));
mb.Bindings.Add(new Binding("MemberCount"));

FrameworkElementFactory textElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, mb);
d.VisualTree = textElement;

style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ComboBox.ItemTemplateProperty, d));
this.Resources.Add("ComboBox_EntityCreation_GroupSelect_Style", style);
```

You can assign a DataTemplate to its VisualTree using FrameworkElementFactory.

Answer (score 1):

Generating templates by code is done via factories (ie. FrameworkElementFactory). You can generate a factory by a FrameworkElement type and set bindings etc. via methods on the factory.

Similar question and a simple example is given on msdn: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f230804d-fc0f-4321-a61e-69a2c890b28d/

Comment: thanks but I chose abhishek's answer because of the code sample